# I need to create a collection with schema validation and add indexing keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a MongoDB collection using nodejs using require('mongodb').MongoClient;

The collection created and accepts indexing by param code as I specify on "doIndexing(keys, options)".

However, it completely ignores the validation on $jsonSchema.

I tried playing with the order but that did not work as I need to create the collection first then try to add the index.

see the code below.

```
const BaseRepository = require('../../../db/baseRepository');
const getMongoDBClient = require('../../../db/mongodbClient');

class LanguageRepository //extends BaseRepository
{
    constructor()
    {
        const collectionName = 'languages';
        this.dbClient = getMongoDBClient();
        this.collection = collectionName;
        // key indexing
        const keys = {code: 1};
        const options = {
            sparse: true,
            unique: true
        };

        // 2
        this.doValidation(keys, options)
    }

    doValidation(keys, options)
    {
        console.log("start doValidation for "+ this.collection);

        this.dbClient
            .then(db => {
                db.createCollection(this.collection, {
                    validator: {
                        $jsonSchema: {
                            bsonType  : "object",
                            required  : ["code"],
                            properties: {
                                // code must be 2 letter A-Z a-z
                                // todo check why it is not working
                                test: {
                                    // pattern : "[a-zA-Z]{2}"
                                    bsonType: "int",
                                    minimum : 2017,
                                    maximum : 3017,
                                }

                            } // properties
                        } // jsonSchema
                    } // validator
                }); // create
            }) // then
            .catch(err => console.log('lag repo ++++++++ ' + err));

        console.log("end doValidation for "+ this.collection);

        // 3
        this.doIndexing(keys, options);

    }

    doIndexing(keys, options){
        console.log("start doIndexing for " + this.collection);

        this.dbClient
            .then(db => db
                .collection(this.collection)
                .createIndex(keys, options));

        console.log("end doIndexing for " + this.collection);
    }

    add(item)
    {
        return this.dbClient
                   .then(db => db
                       .collection(this.collection)
                       .insertOne(item));
    }
}

module.exports = LanguageRepository;
```

I would love to have the validation works fine so the api handle any request that does not meet the requirement

Comment: node v10.15.3     mondoDB mongodb-osx-x86_64-4.0.11

Comment: this works for me and rejects documents that don't comply.  maybe you could include the details what "it completely ignores the validation on $jsonSchema" means and how you tested it.